# Checking the ending of an email

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently building an app that is exclusive to my university. To use the app, you must sign up with your university email. I'm using Parse as a backend server and I would like to check if the email belongs to the university.

So for example, let's say my university email ends with:

**liu.edu.com**

I should check whether the following email is part of that address.

imc@liu.edu.com; belongs to university
imc@hotmail.com; does not belong to university, not allowed to sign up.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `NSString`?

Comment: does your backend server do the job of filtering the right email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the `hasSuffix:` method and search for the domain from the end.

```
NSString* anEmail = @"imc@hotmail.com";
NSString* const eduEmail = @"liu.edu.com";

if([anEmail hasSuffix:eduEmail]) {
    //Valid university email
}
else {
    //Invalid university email
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use the `hasSuffix:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy Sounds like a better way. I’ll edit my answer.